# How to iterate a JSON array in bash from jq

Tags: json, bash, jq, wp-cli

### Background

I want to be able to pass a json file to WP CLI, to iteratively create posts.

So I thought I could create a JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "post_type": "post",
        "post_title": "Test",
        "post_content": "[leaflet-map][leaflet-marker]",
        "post_status": "publish"
    },
    {
        "post_type": "post",
        "post_title": "Number 2",
        "post_content": "[leaflet-map fitbounds][leaflet-circle]",
        "post_status": "publish"
    }
]
```

and iterate the array with jq:

```sh
cat posts.json | jq --raw-output .[]
```

I want to be able to iterate these to execute a similar function:

```sh
wp post create \
  --post_type=post \
  --post_title='Test Map' \
  --post_content='[leaflet-map] [leaflet-marker]' \
  --post_status='publish'
```

Is there a way I can do this with `jq`, or similar?

The closest I've gotten so far is this:

```sh
> for i in $(cat posts.json | jq -c .[]); do echo $i; done
```

But this seems to take issue with the (valid) spaces in the strings.  Output:

```sh
{"post_type":"post","post_title":"Test","post_content":"[leaflet-map][leaflet-marker]","post_status":"publish"}
{"post_type":"post","post_title":"Number
2","post_content":"[leaflet-map
fitbounds][leaflet-circle]","post_status":"publish"}
```

Am I way off with this approach, or can it be done?

Comment: c.f. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/ - `-c` explicitly says to squeeze out whitespace such as newline characters. Try `--indent n` inside the loop, but `-c` to generate your data. Loop with `while read -r i;do echo "$i"|jq --indent 2 '.'; echo "==="; done < <( jq -c '.[]' posts.json )
`

Answer (score 7):

Use a `while` to read entire lines, rather than iterating over the *words* resulting from the command substitution.

```
while IFS= read -r obj; do
    ...
done < <(jq -c '.[]' posts.json)
```

Comment: great idea. couldn't for the life of me get this working until stumbling upon your solution

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work for you:

Make a bash executable, maybe call it `wpfunction.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

wp post create \
  --post_type="$1"\
  --post_title="$2" \
  --post_content="$3" \
  --post_status="$4"
```

Then run `jq` on your `posts.json` and pipe it into `xargs`

```
jq -M -c '.[] | [.post_type, .post_title, .post_content, .post_status][]' \
posts.json | xargs -n4 ./wpfunction`
```

I am experimenting to see how this would handle post_content that contained quotes...

Answer (score 1):

First generate an array of the arguments you wish to pass then convert to a shell compatible form using `@sh`. Then you could pass to xargs to invoke the command.

```
$ jq -r '.[] | ["post", "create", (to_entries[] | "--\(.key)=\(.value|tojson)")] | @sh' input.json | xargs wp
```